# No connection to kernel - Jupyter Notebook Windows 10

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have Python3 pre-installed on my personal laptop and now i have installed Jupyter Notebook using PIP but when i create a new notebook using python 3 kernel, it always gives orange highlighted message "Connecting to Kernel" but never connects.
OS - Windows 10, Personal laptop
Network - Wifi and not connecting through any proxy
Anti-virus - Uninstalled

Can someone help what could be the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer on stack overflow only in another thread.

Uninstall tornado 6

```
pip uninstall tornado
```

and reinstall tornado 5

```
pip install tornado==5.1.1
```

Comment: Yeah, even I was facing the same issue; But for me, 4.2.1 version of the tornado has worked. So, if 5.1.x does not work use 4.2.x it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue,i tried uninstalling tornado and reinstalling it ,i tried running it on different port , none of those worked.but i tried this and worked!!!!!
open anaconda ===> Home ====> find jupyter notebook ====> go to the gear icon (settings) ===> first remove it then  you see there is a  install button under it,after installation it worked for me!!!!

Answer (score 0):

After having issues with this myself, and looking at the Tornado version, I found this wasn't the problem for me, instead after running the following in the relevant environment after installing ipykernel, this resolved the issue:

conda install -n base nb_conda_kernels

Answer (score -1):

```
jupyter kernelspec list
```

Should list all kernels running on your system, make sure that the Python kernel path is accurate.

I would also try to run it over another port, in case if any network restrictions

Comment: I have seen the list and it shows only one kernel i.e. python 3 and path is correct.

Comment: How can i check it there is any network restriction as i am accessing in my personal laptop with no anti-virus or proxy.

Comment: @AnujN There is no single command to find "network restrictions." However, to eliminate this possibility, I would run it on a different port.

`jupyter notebook --port 8080`